# How to use OSMnx with Django?

Tags: python, django, conda, osmnx

I want to create app that will calculate route between given points on map. I'm using Conda for managing my environment. In my venv I have installed Django and OSMnx. After adding OSMnx server won't run. The stacktrace is pretty long and ends with this:

```
    with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
AttributeError: module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading'
```

In my Django project i have one app called planner and the view is using OSMnx (not sure if this code should go there) and it looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    
    # As for now it is ok to hardcode place and network type
    warsaw_streets = ox.graph_from_place("Warsaw", network_type="drive")
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Im new to Django and I don't know if I'm using external library wrong or what is the purpose of this error...

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and complete details on how you installed OSMnx. Note the specific installation [instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation).

Comment: Yea, thanks! it was a installation issue. I managed to solve it and posted the answer that worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! First time I created conda env and install Django by 'conda install Django' then osmnx 'conda install osmnx' and it didn't worked. I tried other way:

1. conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
2. conda create --prefix ./venv --strict-channel-priority osmnx
3. activate created venv
4. pip install Django

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your OSMnx library has the error.

You can try:

1. installing an older, stable version of OSMnx
2. using a different python library

Comment: OSMnx does not use fiona directly. Its dependency, GeoPandas, does however, so this is more likely an installation issue.